# Query is possibly slow?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am not sure what normal is with postgres.

I'm running this on a `postgres` instance in `Google Cloud` where the managed VM, I've tried tweaking even up to `4GB` Ram and `4` cpu, but didn't really make any difference.

The query below takes 200-300ms to run each time and that adds up as I am looping for each `country_id` and so this is called probably 50 times from my JavaScript code:

```
select
 c.community_id,
 c.name
 from community c
 join community_location cl on cl.community_id = c.community_id
 join location l on cl.location_id = l.location_id
where l.country_id = 60
```

**Execution Time**: `223ms`

The tables themselves are very small, no more than 200 rows in community or location.

Is is reasonable for this to take that long?  Or is this just a badly formed query?

Here's the explain run of it:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=1.79..5.54 rows=4 width=40)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.65..3.29 rows=4 width=4)"
"        Hash Cond: (cl.location_id = l.location_id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on community_location cl  (cost=0.00..1.50 rows=50 width=8)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1.60..1.60 rows=4 width=4)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on location l  (cost=0.00..1.60 rows=4 width=4)"
"                    Filter: (country_id = 60)"
"  ->  Index Scan using community_pkey on community c  (cost=0.14..0.56 rows=1 width=40)"
"        Index Cond: (community_id = cl.community_id)"
```

I tried also running this query, instead of calling it each time from my JS code, and just trying to hard code with an `IN` all the country IDs my JavaScript is looping with for country, but same speed basically when I run the query straight up with `IN`:

```
select
 c.community_id,
 c.name
 from community c
 join community_location cl on cl.community_id = c.community_id
 join location l on cl.location_id = l.location_id
where l.country_id in (
    6,
    8,
    9,
    26,
    23,
    32,
    35,
    44,
    60,
    64,
    66,
    77,
    81,
    83,
    93,
    116,
    123,
    131,
    137,
    138,
    142,
    153,
    164,
    169,
    178,
    184,
    185
)
```

**Execution time**: `232ms`

Execute result:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=5.57..9.91 rows=33 width=40)"
"  Hash Cond: (c.community_id = cl.community_id)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on community c  (cost=0.00..3.74 rows=74 width=40)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=5.15..5.15 rows=33 width=4)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.51..5.15 rows=33 width=4)"
"              Hash Cond: (cl.location_id = l.location_id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on community_location cl  (cost=0.00..1.50 rows=50 width=8)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=3.10..3.10 rows=33 width=4)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on location l  (cost=0.00..3.10 rows=33 width=4)"
"                          Filter: (country_id = ANY ('{6,8,9,26,23,32,35,44,60,64,66,77,81,83,93,116,123,131,137,138,142,153,164,169,178,184,185}'::integer[]))"
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Instead of looping for each `country_id` you could just join to your source of `country_id`s in your query - likely a country table? Then you just need to also select this column, this can then take advantage of bulk friendly operations like table scans and hash joins. In terms of this individual query being slow... it depends on how much work it's achieving - think about the amount of `location` rows that match a `country_id` and how many rows you need to look at for each join - are there appropriate indexes to support those lookups...

Comment: ok let me run explain and will report back

Comment: yea I could change the structure of the data coming back and maybe save from having to loop but reason I loop is because I ultimately map these records into domain objects upstream in my app

Comment: >are there appropriate indexes to support those lookups : No I haven't added any indexes

Comment: definitely you are missing  indexes on `location` and `community_location` tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
select c.community_id, c.name
from community c join
     community_location cl
     on cl.community_id = c.community_id join
     location l
     on cl.location_id = l.location_id
where l.country_id = 60;
```

You want the following indexes:

- `location(country_id, location_id)`
- `community_location(location_id, community_id)`
- `community(community_id)`